# Installing Zend framework with WAMP server

Tags: zend-framework, wamp

I'm trying to install Zend framework on a WAMP server but it is not working properly.

I downloaded the Zend framework and created the folder in `C:\wamp\library\Zend`, and then in `php.inc` I have something like this:

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes:C:\wamp\library"
```

Now when I try to run the sample `blogger.php` it is giving me the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\PHPSample\Blogger.php on line 37

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\wamp\www\PHPSample\Blogger.php on line 37
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Windows your php.ini should have a section like this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"  
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
```

The key is to a) remove the semi-colon at the beginning of the line, and b) add what you need to the path. **NOTE:** on Windows, paths must be separated by semi-colons, whereas on UNIX they are separated by full colons; Also, Dot means "current directory", so only include it if you want to.

Make sure it looks like this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;c:\wamp\library"
```

Comment: I try to upload my zend website to a `Shared host`, and i cant change `php.ini`, Is there any other way to run zend framework on shared host?

Answer (score 10):

Zend Installation:- Download Zend Framework

- Go to Wamp/bin/php/
  Create a folder Namely:- Zend_Framework
- Copy All the Files and Folder of Downloaded Zend Framework.
- Go to php.ini and find include_path
  Here you find:- include_path="`c:\php\includes`"
  and replace the text between "" from  your directory  `C:\wamp\bin\php\zend_framework\library`
  and Save File.
- Now Go to Computer Property and Advanced System Setting and Advanced and Environment Variable and
  select path from system variables and click on Edit and add ; and paste your directory path hare 
  C:\wamp\bin\php\zend_framework\bin
- Open Command Prompt and go to the www directory inside wamp and then type zf create project Zendy
- Now go to httpd.conf file and type there `<virtualHost></virtualHost>` Tags.

`<virtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:\www\Zendy\public"
    ServerName Zendy
    <Directory "C:\www\Zendy\public">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options
        order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</virtualHost>`

- Save and Quit and go to windows -> System32 -> drivers-> etc-> hosts  and Add here your project 
  `127.0.0.1` localhost Zendy
- Save and Quit and Restart Apache
- Also set rewrite module  via removing ; from `php.ini` file

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 4):

i had made this cast explaining how to setup Many ZF Application  with Wamp full functional 
please check it out and let me know if you had any problem so i can help :

[Getting Started with the Zend Framework and WAMP Server](http://www.zendcasts.com/getting-started-with-zend-and-wamp-server/2009/06/)

Answer (score 0):

that should work if:

you unpacked contents of the library folder in archive that contains Zend framework in

C:\wamp\library folder. othervise you need to do that ( put the contents of the library folder in archive in path you specified in php.ini