# How To Install Zend Framework On Wamp?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hello guys i am having big problems in zend framework i dont know how to install zend framework on wamp can any one guide me please i totally sick up and fed up please guide me how to install zend

Comment: @Tayyab Gulsher Vohra - this might help [installing zend framework with wamp server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699995/installing-zend-framework-with-wamp-server)

Comment: -1 Offtopic : someone please migrate this

Comment: Why this question has been migrated to SO? It doesn't belong here. It belongs to http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: [Download](http://framework.zend.com/download/latest).  Scroll to the ones that say "zip | tar.gz" instead of "free download" to bypass their *stupid* email harvester.

Step 2: Extract it somewhere that your code can reference.

Step 3: Use it by referencing one of the components as needed.

There are no special steps needed, no extra things that need to be installed, nothing.  Just put the library somewhere and make use of it.

Comment: ZF v1 requires the `library` directory be on the include path as it's rife with `require_once 'Zend/...'` calls.

Comment: @Phil, shouldn't it be using `Zend_Loader`, like a nice little library?  I haven't noticed problems with the specific parts of ZF that I use, with regard to incorrectly-pathed includes.

Comment: @Charles Every class file in ZF v1 adds all required dependencies to the top of the file via `require_once` calls (v2 will remove these in favour of the autoloader). The paths specified in the `require` calls all start with `Zend/`, requiring the "Zend" folder be inside the `include_path`. This is usually and easily handled by the application using `set_include_path()` however I thought I'd mention it as one more required step

Comment: hello guys sorry but i dont understand what you people have said it goes over my head i request any one who can write simple steps one by one please dont mind i am a new born baby in php.

Comment: @Tayyab, can you please explain where you get stuck on the *three simple steps* I posted above?  If you are very new to PHP, I would actually advise you to *avoid* frameworks until you are more familiar with the language and understand all the pitfalls that frameworks can help solve.