# How to install Zend Framework 2.0 on wamp?

Tags: zend-framework2

I am new to Zend Framework and I want to configure Zend Framework 2.0 on wamp.
Can any one give me step by step procedure for ZF 2.0

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452294/how-to-install-zend-framework-on-wamp?rq=1

Comment: I am familier with older versions of zf but I am specifically talking about zf2.0 which is latest

Comment: This is for XAMP, but it will help you too http://samminds.com/2012/07/zend-framework-2-installation-on-xampp-for-windows/