# problem with include in PHP

Tags: php

In my www folder I have a folder called openslopeone. Inside openslopeone I have a file called OpenSlopeOne.php. In my www folder I have a file called test.php in which I did:

require_once ('openslopeone/OpenSlopeOne.php');

however, now I am getting the following error:
[image]

Here's the include/require code from OpenSlopeOne.php

```
set_include_path('./inc');

require_once 'Zend/Db.php';
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
```

Inside the folder inc I have the folder Zend, which contains Db.php and Loader.php

What am I missing here

Comment: check include path setting by "echo get_include_path();"

Comment: I would say that `/Zend` is not found within `./inc`

Comment: There is a folder called Zend inside inc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is telling you that it cannot find the "Zend/Db.php" file. Edited for brain fart, thx.

Comment: No, it's saying it can't find `Zend/Db.php`. It can find `openslopeone/OpenSlopeOne.php` just fine.

Comment: yea, I think it can find OpenSlopeOne.php fine, but why can't it find Db.php? It is there actually

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong include path for Zend framework; see [Installing Zend framework with WAMP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699995/installing-zend-framework-with-wamp-server)

Comment: but why does it work if I put test.php inside the folder openslopeone?